# How do I make a script asks the user for input to put in a variable in the script itself?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

As the question suggests, I made a script that inserts a specific statement in a specific line in *.ovpn file, How can I make the * as an input argument so that the script will ask me for it when I execute it?
(I'm using EOF but I can switch to any other method that works).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created script.sh and used there variable provided by user

./script '*'

```
    #!/usr/bin/env bash
    echo "Enter Text For Variable"
    read my_var
    echo "Your variable is used as you can see *.$my_var"
    echo "Positional variable is here $1"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked for me perfectly!

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `read -p`:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p  "Enter filename: " filename
echo "Your file is: $filename.ovpn"
```

Comment: thanks, it works too :)